# how to set default applications in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, notepad, dreamweaver

I have .php files on my www directory but the default application used for opening them is notepad. How do I change it to dreamweaver?

Comment: ...is this actually the only time this question has been asked? I couldn't find another question asking how to change default Windows programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on any PHP file and select **Open with**... (if it's not displayed in the right click menu try pressing Shift and then right click) and select **Choose Default Program**.

Browse to Program Files and open the Dreamweaver installation folder and select Dreamweaver.exe

Comment: it wont work. I even right click and selected default program, but its not affected, when I try to open the folder where the file is located. It is still notepad

Comment: windows 7 is dumb. it shows the file as text file but when you double click it will open with dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2):

Right click over a .php file.

Select "Open With" then "Choose Default Program..."

Browse to Program Files to find Dreamweaver.